# Print Archive::Zip zip file to Apache2::RequestIO object

Tags: perl, apache, apache2, zip, mod-perl

I have a website using mod_perl.

I'm creating a zip file in memory (using `Archive::Zip`), and I want to serve that file without having to write it to disk.

`Archive::Zip` will only output to a specified file handle, and I don't think `Apache2::RequestIO` provides me with one.

At the moment I just print the Zip file to *STDOUT and that works. But I'm sure there's a better way to do it. I'm printing everything else through the RequestRec object, e.g. `$r->print(...)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should help...

```
use Archive::Zip;
my $zip = Archive::Zip->new();
#create your zip here

use IO::Scalar;
my $memory_file = '';   #scalar as a file
my $memfile_fh = IO::Scalar->new(\$memory_file); #filehandle to the scalar

# write to the scalar $memory_file
my $status = $zip->writeToFileHandle($memfile_fh);
$memfile_fh->close;

#print with apache
#$r->content_type(".......");
$r->print($memory_file);    #the content of a file-in-a-scalar
```

EDIT:
The above is obsoloted. 
from the [Archive::Zip](http://search.cpan.org/~adamk/Archive-Zip-1.30/lib/Archive/Zip.pm) docs:

> Try to avoid IO::Scalar
>
> One of the most common ways to use Archive::Zip is to generate Zip
>   files in-memory. Most people have use IO::Scalar for this purpose.
>
> Unfortunately, as of 1.11 this module no longer works with IO::Scalar
>   as it incorrectly implements seeking.
>
> Anybody using IO::Scalar should consider porting to IO::String, which
>   is smaller, lighter, and is implemented to be perfectly compatible
>   with regular seekable filehandles.
>
> Support for IO::Scalar most likely will not be restored in the future,
>   as IO::Scalar itself cannot change the way it is implemented due to
>   back-compatibility issues.

Answer (score 2):

In versions of Perl 5.8+, it seems like you can skip IO::Scalar and IO::String all together.

```
use Archive::Zip qw( :ERROR_CODES :CONSTANTS );
my $zip = Archive::Zip->new();

my $memory_file = '';   #scalar as a file
open(my $fh, '>', \$memory_file) || die "Couldn't open memory file: $!";

my $status = $zip->writeToFileHandle($fh);
$fh->close;

$r->print($memory_file);
```

I think there is probably a more optimal way of doing this, but it works...